# MS-Access error: At most one record can be returned by this subquery

Tags: ms-access, subquery

When I am trying to run this query it gives me error "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

```
SELECT * from rosterTbl 
WHERE 
rosterTbl.CounsellorID IN (IIF (ISNULL([Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor]) , (SELECT counsellorID FROM
[Main: Counsellors_Tbl]),[Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor]))
```

Comment: The `IIF` function is intended to return discrete values, not query results.  The value of `[Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor]` should be returned OK, but I have no idea what the `IIF` returns from `SELECT counsellorID FROM
[Main: Counsellors_Tbl]`.

Comment: Do you know the other way How could I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're trying to accomplish, your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT * from rosterTbl 
WHERE [Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor] IS NULL
OR rosterTbl.CounsellorID 
IN (SELECT counsellorID FROM [Main: Counsellors_Tbl])
```

Comment: It will gives me all records because you are using {OR} Operator.

Comment: No, because if `Forms!ReportsGUI!cmbCounsellor` is not NULL, then records must fulfill the other condition to be returned from the query.

Comment: I need this result IF `Forms!ReportsGUI!cmbCounsellor IS NULL` THEN Query returns all records otherwise it gives me the specific counsellor record

Comment: Its working I changed clause like this 
`([Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor] IS NULL OR rosterTbl.CounsellorID = ([Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor]))`